# Telerik MVC3 grid - batch editing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I using a Telerik MVC Grid and configured it for Batch Mode Editing http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingbatch. I am trying to edit one of my entity "State" which has List of Cities, where City is another entity. Here is how the State Entity looks.

```
public class State {
    ...Some Scalar Properties
    public virtual List<City> Cities { get; set; }  //Navigation Property
    public State() {  
        Cities = new List<City>();
    }
}
```

My City Entity points back to State as given below.

```
public class City {
     ... Some Scalar Properties
    public virtual State State { get; set; }  //Navigation property
}
```

I am using this Model in one of my cshtml pages some thing like this

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<State>()
            .Name("tlkStateGrid")
            .Editable(e =>  e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
            .ToolBar(t => {
                t.Insert().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
                t.SubmitChanges().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
            })

 ...Some More of code here.
```

In my Controller I am handling the batch updates in normal way.

```
public ActionResult _SaveChanges(IEnumerable<State> inserted, IEnumerable<State> updated, IEnumerable<State> deleted) {
.....
}
```

When I try to edit State entity using batching editing of Telerik Grid, the (IEnumerable updated) parameter of the above controller action has entries for all the States that have been modified. The States however have a Cities List with one city (which is null) even if there aren't any Cities in the State.

So the point is that I have not created any City in any part of my code, but when I receive the States as parameter to the controller action listed above, there is a null City sitting inside the Cities List. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the problem.  So when the grid posts, you create a new *State*.  Attached to that *State* object, there's a null *City* object.  Is that the issue?  Or did I miss something?

If that's the issue, it's normal behavior and should be expected. That is how the automatic JSON de-serialization in MVC3 works--any time you create a parent object and don't define the nested object, the nested object will be returned as null.  Just handle the nulls in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have decided not to use batch editing in grid. It was rather confusing for the user. Nice to see that the question still gets answered even after such a long gap. Great.

Comment: No problem, man.  If I had seen this before I would have answered earlier.  I agree, I thought batch editing would be confusing for the user, but my user actually wanted the editing process to "be more like Excel".  Go figure.